# LMER returns errors, but Repeated Measures ANOVA on the same data doesn't, why?

Tags: r, anova, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, panel-data

everyone!
So, I've been trying to fit a LMER for my data, which I fully described [in this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/586633/fitting-a-lmer-with-longitudinal-data-for-2-categorical-predictors) .
This post, therefore, is a follow-up from the previous one. There's something intriguing me, I don't get any errors when I run this ANOVA:

```
aov(SCORE ~ LANGUAGE * YEAR + Error(SUBJECT/LANGUAGE * YEAR), data = data)
```

but I'm getting the a non-converge error (model1) or a boundary error (specifically for the language variable) model2:

```
model1 <- lmer(SCORE ~ (YEAR * LANGUAGE | SUBJECT), data = data
Error: number of observations (=80) <= number of random effects (=80) for term (YEAR * LANGUAGE | SUBJECT); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable

or

model2 <- lmer(SCORE ~ LANGUAGE * YEAR + (YEAR | SUBJECT) + (LANGUAGE|SUBJECT), data = data
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

As far as I'm concerned, this lmer should resseamble the repeated measures ANOVA I've ran before, so why do I get an error for the model, but not for the Anova?

Any thoughts on it would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure about the first error, but my guess is you get singular fit from lmer because you have too few observations (or other data-related issues) to estimate the random slope, which is usually the most complex part to estimate. If I understood correctly, you only had 2 observations per participant per year - that is usually too few for random slope estimation. Repeated-measures ANOVA does not estimate the year-specific slope, so it works out.

Comment: @Sointu , thank you for your answer, so this ANOVA argument: ```Error(SUBJECT/LANGUAGE * YEAR)``` is equal to lmer(SCORE ~ Language*Year + (1|SUBJECT), data = data) ? I thought that the corresponding model to that Anova was one from the ones that I've ran before, but now I'm wondering this...

Comment: To the best of my understanding, not quite as I don't think ANOVA calculates subject-specific intercepts as lmer does with the (1|subject), it just handles the correlated errors (?), but I'd say from a practical point of view a random intercept lmer and repeated measures anova usually give roughly similar results. However I might be wrong as I rarely use ANOVAs, I only wanted to comment on the lmer singular fit error as I'm familiar with it myself! I hope you'll get a better answer soon!

Comment: @Sointu , no problem! thank you very much for your insights! 